# C# Calling Web Services to different URLs

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I'm new to Web Services from C#, but have worked C# for years, just never needed to use Web Services.  Due to privacy issues, I can't disclose actual URL, but there is a test server and a production server where the web services are identical in all other respects, and the services were written / managed by another entity.

https://LiveSite.SomeDomain.com/FolderInWebSite/TestWebServiceSoapHTTP

and

https://TestSite.SomeDomain.com/FolderInWebSite/TestWebServiceSoapHTTP

Do I need to create two separate web references to the project and create different instances of them to go, or can I via some property just change which URL version it is sending data to.

Additionally, not being familiar working web services, I see the classes as Visual Studio imported.  I can create instances of the classes and set the applicable properties (int, dates, strings, string[] arrays, etc).  But not seeing how to actually say ... Go send it now. and then getting the response back.

I've done this from an older application with another language and was doing direct with HTTP and SOAP where I was able to make my own connection to the URL, build the body of the SOAP message, then send it.

Comment: I don't have a project set up to test, but you pass in the URL you want, maybe in the constructor?  As far as telling it to go, just invoke the method.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the "Url" property.

```
var myProxy = new MyProxy();
myProxy.Url = "http://foo.com/myservice";
```

Edit for second part of the question:

There should be a method for each action exposed the API that you can call. For example if the API exposes a MyAction that takes a string, the code generator should have generated a method that you can use like so:

```
myProxy.MyAction("hello");
```